# User that left the organization and came back is unable to access SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, user-profile, profile-sync

We have a user that is trying to access a site collection. I've given her owner rights but she is still unable to access the site collection.  I think it's worth mentioning that this user left the organization for awhile and came back.  It almost appears as though her profile isn't syncing properly.  Is there a way to force a resync with Active Directory?  We aren't currently using the User Profile Sync service to my knowledge.

Comment: Ask your helpdesk/sysadmins what was done with this person's Active Directory account when they left and returned. Profile has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the user's AD account as deactivated, and then reactivated, then they should still have access. If their account was deleted and then recreated, then they have a new SID and are not the same user.

I think the Move-SPUser PowerShell cmdlet will help you fix this. (Do a web search first.)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps